# convert decimal degrees to degrees minutes and then decimal seconds

Tags: math, gps, coordinates

I am successfully using the PHP code below (great resources on here!) to change decimal degrees to degrees minutes seconds. The nav apps I'm using export the coordinates as decimal, so 50.360503 and display 50°21.638N. In marine navigation we use degrees minutes and then tenths instead of true seconds when working with paper charts.

Could any of you give me some pointers with how to change the decimal instead of the code below?

```
function convertDecimalToDMSLongitude($dec)
{

// Converts decimal longitude / latitude to DMS
// ( Degrees / minutes / seconds )
// This is the piece of code which may appear to
// be inefficient, but to avoid issues with floating
// point math we extract the integer part and the float
// part by using a string function.

$vars = explode(".",$dec);
$deg = $vars[0];
$tempma = "0.".$vars[1];

$tempma = $tempma * 3600;
$min = floor($tempma / 60);
$sec = $tempma - ($min*60);
$sec = number_format($sec, 0);


if ($deg <= 0) {
  $hemisphere = 'W';
} else {
  $hemisphere = 'E';
}

$degrees = abs($deg);
if ($degrees <= 9) {
  $deg = '00'.$degrees;
} elseif ($degrees >= 10) {
  $deg = '0'.$degrees;
} elseif ($degrees >= 100) {
  $deg = $degrees;
}

return $deg.'.'.$min.'.'.$sec.''.$hemisphere;
}
```

I have this (below) so far which is close; it's returning 50°21630180.N when inputting 50.360503 as the decimal. I Just need to split out the 21 minutes from the remaining figure. The GPS app (Navionics or iSailor) exports as the decimal and shows 50°21.638N on screen.

```
$vars = explode(".",$dec);
$deg = $vars[0];
$tempma = "0.".$vars[1];

//$tempma = $tempma * 3600;
//$min = floor($tempma / 60);
//$sec = $tempma - ($min*60);
//$sec = number_format($sec, 0);

$min = $vars[1]*60;

$sec = '';

if ($deg >= 0) {
  $hemisphere = 'N';
} else {
  $hemisphere = 'S';
}

return abs($deg).'.'.$min.'.'.$sec.' '.$hemisphere;
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
$vars = explode(".",$dec);
$deg = $vars[0];
$min = "0.".$vars[1];

$min = $min * 3600;
$min = $min / 60;
$min = number_format((float)$min, 3, '.', '');


if ($deg <= 0) {
  $hemisphere = 'W';
} else {
  $hemisphere = 'E';
}

//add 00 if single degrees
$degrees = abs($deg);
if ($degrees <= 9) {
  $deg = '00'.$degrees;
} elseif ($degrees >= 10) {
  $deg = '0'.$degrees;
} elseif ($degrees >= 100) {
  $deg = $degrees;
}

//add a 0 if a single number
if ($min <= 9) {
  $min = '0'.$min;
}

return $deg.'° '.$min.' '.$hemisphere;
```